# is there a way to overwrite a file under repository by a local file out of repository

Tags: svn, merge

My purpose is to merge a branch to the trunk, but since too many changes, that cost a lot of time.
So, I find out to get the change file list by svn diff, but, I find can not overwrite the file under repo by a local file out of repo. Can anyone help?

Comment: A merge is the proper way to do this. Take the hit this time, and take it as lesson to perform merges more often to lessen the impact in the future.